# Помогите написать на Си программу для подсчета слов

Tags: c

Задача состоит в том, чтобы подсчитать в тексте количество определенных слов.
Нужно написать на Си.

Вот что сам сумел написать:

```
int main()
{
   char s[100];
   int k;
   FILE *f1 = fopen("ServerSocket1.txt", "r");
   while(fgets(s, 100, f1))
   {
        if(strstr(s,"библиотек") != NULL) //здесь хотел чтобы если в строке есть совпадение, то к счетчику прибавляем 1
            k++;
   }
    printf("%d", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42325/discussion-on-question-by---------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При кривой кодировке strstr ничего не посчитает. Не знаю откуда Вы берете этот файл. Но попробуйте просто создать текстовый файлик с несколькими нужными словами и сохраните его, например, в utf8. Для начала сделайте все в латинице. А потом проверьте в кирилице.

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло)

Comment: Если ответ верный, то он отмечается галочкой (слева под цифрой).

Comment: @Артём Молчанов Вот... теперь спасибо и булькает и в карман покладено :) ... Как говорится, всегда пожалуйста.